# Find $f(x)$ if $f$ is a polynomial and $f(x) + f'(x) = x^3 + 5x^2 + x + 2$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, derivatives, polynomials

> If
>   $$f(x)+f'(x)=x^3+5x^2+x+2$$
>   find $f$, if it is a polynomial function.

The answer given is : $f(x) = x^3+2x^2-3x+5$. Please anyone explain simple way to solve.

Comment: You have just answered a similar question minutes ago and you repost one without showing effort. This is **exactly** the same as your previous one.

Comment: What do you know about differential equations, what work have you done on this problem, and exactly where are you stuck? For example, do you understand [the method of undetermined coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_undetermined_coefficients)?

Comment: this is a different ! i couldn't understand the equation on this formula

Comment: your solution is not correct

Comment: no it's correct .. that is the figure in book

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $f(x)$ be $ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, then $f'(x)$ is $3ax^2 + 2bx +c$ . Adding them we get, $ax^3 +x^2(b+3a) +x(c+2b) + d+c$. Comparing with the given equation, $a = 1$, $b =2$, $c=-3$,  $d=5$.
So, $f(x)$ is obtained.

Comment: thanks for your help :) @Vikas Rv

Answer (score 1):

at first solve the equation $$y(x)+y'(x)=0$$
write $$\frac{dy}{dx}+y=0$$ or $$\frac{dy}{y}=-dx$$ and integrate

Comment: what this mean ?

Comment: this is a differential equation,linear and of first order

Comment: but it's not equal 0 ?

Comment: no it is $$\log(|y|)=-x+C$$

Comment: The question says **find** $f$ **if it is a polynomial function**

Comment: I'm surprised to see this answer got upvoted so much. This doesn't help at all and OP clearly doesn't know differential equations

Comment: How does finding the solution $y(x) = Ce ^{-x}$ of the homogeneous differential equation $y'+y=0$  help to find a particular *polynomial* solution of the  given inhomogeneous differential equation?